# Getting insertID using currentproject.connection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wanted to get the insert ID of the  the last insert query

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

cn.Execute "Insert into Locations(locationName) Values('" & Me.location.Value & "')"

rs.Open "SELECT @@identity AS locationID FROM locations", cn

Debug.Print rs.Fields("locationID")
```

However, this always returns 0 . Is there a way to get the insertID using the ADO connection?

Edit1:

With the help of the reply below and further research I found out the soultion

I forgot to mention that my backend database is mysql database not MSSQL or Access. I also changed my code to use global connection now which is named `g_cn`. I think `currentproject.connection` does not work with backend mysql database to get the insertionID because it uses DAO connection.

I set the global connection by doing:

```
g_cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=" & gc_DevServerName & ";Database=" & gc_DevDBName & ";Uid=" & gc_DevUser & ";Pwd=" & gc_DevPassword & ";Option=3;"
```

I can now use ADO. So my code changed to :

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Insert into Locations(locationName) Values('" & Me.location.Value & "')", g_cn
rs.Open "Select LAST_INSERT_ID() as last from locations;", g_cn
Debug.Print rs.Fields("last")
rs.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT @@identity` is a special query in Access. You can't use it with a `FROM` clause. Remove that and the query will work:

```
rs.Open "SELECT @@identity AS locationID", cn
```

Comment: I removed the from clause and it still gives me 0.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, sorry. I've tried and tested the code. Are you sure you have an autonumber field for the primary key?

Comment: I forgot to metion that my database is mysql. I found the solution and have updated the question with the solution